# angular routeprovider with authentication on nodejs

Tags: angularjs, node.js, ngroute

I'm currently experimenting a little bit with my first app with angular-js, nodejs and a mongodb backend. This app and its URLs are managed by ngRoute from angular. In this app there is a little admin area with authentication (based on nodejs' client-sessions). This works so far pretty well. The authentication works with URLs managed by nodejs, but not with the ones of the routeProvider. The provider looks like this:

```js
app.config(['$locationProvider', '$routeProvider', function ($locationProvider, $routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.when("/main",
        {
            templateUrl: "app/main/landing.html",
            controller: "MainController"
        })
        .when("/admin",
            {
                templateUrl: "restricted",
                controller: "AdminController"
            })
        .when("/login",
            {
                templateUrl: "app/login/login.html"
            })

        .otherwise({redirectTo: '/main'});
}]);
```

The restricted area (/admin) calls a get to the server and sends the view.html if user is valid:

```js
 app.get('/restricted', function (req, res) {

    if (!req.session_state.user) {
        res.res.status(302).redirect("/login");//Does not really work, should redirect to login, but endless loop
    } else {
        res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname + "/../views/restricted/admin.html"));
    }
});
```

The server's restricted folder is outside of the static area provided by nodejs.

The problem is that deep links (when calling directly '#!/admin') there is an endless loop. How can this be solved? I already tried with differnt URLs and status codes. Is this a correct approach to realize authentication with routeProvider or is there a better one?